# Code not working when put in module shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble getting a shiny module to display a table. I think it is a namespace issue, but really, I have no idea. The table data does not display in the module example below. I also include an example of the code working when not using modules.

Nonworking code example using module:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dqshiny)
# module UI ->
myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
        dq_handsontable_output(ns("dataTable"))
    )
  )
}
# module server ->
myModule <- function(input, output, session, df) {
    dq_render_handsontable("dataTable", df)
}
# Use the module in an application
ui <- fluidPage(
  myModuleUI("myModule1")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df = data.frame(
        company = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
        bond = c(0.2, 1, 0.3, 0),
        equity = c(0.7, 0, 0.5, 1),
        cash = c(0.1, 0, 0.2, 0),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  callModule(myModule, "myModule1",  df = df)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code below works without using modules:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dqshiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dq_handsontable_output("dataTable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    df = data.frame(
        company = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
        bond = c(0.2, 1, 0.3, 0),
        equity = c(0.7, 0, 0.5, 1),
        cash = c(0.1, 0, 0.2, 0),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    dq_render_handsontable("dataTable", df)
  }
)
```

Comment: this actually looks like a weird behavior. Just tested the code without `dqshiny` (òutput$dataTable <- render...) and its not working either. Howeder, just using DT works just fine.

Comment: I could make it work with just `rhandsontable` (without `dqshiny`), the trick is to use `output$dataTable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df)})`, then it works in the module. I suspect that `dq_render_handsontable` is the culprit. If you look in the [source code](https://github.com/daqana/dqshiny/blob/master/R/dq_handsontable.R), `dq_handsontable_output` looks ok. But in `dq_render_handsontable` something fishy with modules/scopes is going on (see lines 122-127).

Comment: I think they try to use modules for the filtering/paging for each table, but don't use the standard `shiny` module infrastructure, but instead are directly messing with the `session`s/namespaces. Probably there is something going wrong. E.g. I don't understand why they use `app_output` in line 222 instead of `output` (but it doesn't solve the problem to change it)

Comment: Thanks for posting the source. The source code is essentially calling ```renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df)}``` on ```app_output[[id]]```

Comment: . Also I see the filters and pagination, and dqshiny seems to build those with ```output``` instead of ```app_output```, ```output$filters <- shiny::renderUI({  ... })```.

Comment: Have a look how `app_output` and `output` are defined and compare it what happens when you call [`callModule`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/modules.R). If I understand it correctly, `app_output` is the scope of the calling module and `ouput` the scope of the new module (created for the filtering and pagination); however as it is not done via the shiny module API, I think something goes wrong and it only works if you call it from the main `server` function and not from a module